# Bitbucket Hooks with Apache SSL certificates required

Tags: php, git, apache, ssl, bitbucket

We are trying to implement a simple push/deploy system using Bitbucket's webhooks.  This works properly with our PHP script when Apache is not configured to use the SSLEngine and certificates; however, we cannot seem to figure out how to let Bitbucket post to our web server once we enable certificates.

We have tried changing the client verification at the virtual host to optional, and adding `SSLVerifyClient require` to all directories except the deploy directory.  But it seems like `SSLVerifyClient require`cascades down from the root directory (/myexample/www) to all its sub directories.  Any recommendations on how to configure this properly?

ssl-conf:

```
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /myexample/www

    WSGIScriptAlias / /myexample/www/thingshere/wsgi.py

    <Directory /myexample/www>
        Options Indexes Followsymlinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /myexample/www/deploy>
        Options Indexes Followsymlinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        #Require all granted
        #Allow from 131.103.20.165
        #Allow from 131.103.20.166
    </Directory>

    <Directory /myexample/www/thingshere>
        Options Indexes Followsymlinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory> LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /path/mycert.crt
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/mycertca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/mycertkey.key

    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/mycert.crt
```

Comment: Not sure there's any setting in Bitbucket to make it use a client certificate when using a webhook. Are you trying to make your server accessible with client certs from other clients, and without client certs from Bitbucket?

Comment: @Bruno Yea, that is pretty much exactly what I am trying to do.  I couldn't find any options on Bitbucket for certs as well.